# nexus 4 “storage space running out” issue

Tags: installation, storage

I'm using Nexus 4 which is not rooted.

My phone started to giving me the low memory warning after have lot pic n video recording. I deleted stuff of about 400 MB, but still when I try to install an app, even very small ones, I get an error saying **could not be installed, free up some space and try again**.

Any suggestion how can solve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info?

Comment: yes...I deleted some of app and even media files also...n then restart device as well..it is showing some 400 MB available...but still problem is same...any suggestion?